# Can we use a different language for commandline autocompletion?

Tags: python, bash, shell, autocomplete

I know we can put a bash_completion script in /etc/bash_completion.d, but I kind of dislike writing it because study materials are scarce. For example, is it possible to write a completion script in python?

Comment: Perhaps you could use a stub script that just executes a python script and passes input/output?

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get rid of completly of the bash "api" for completion, but a good part of this api are just global variables (COMPREPLY, COMP_WORDS, ...) so you can easily read/set them in python. 
It's a bit old but you can get a lead how to do that from this https://github.com/gfxmonk/bash-cached-completions.